# Get hashmap byte number for TCP packet fragmentation purpose

Tags: java, object, hashmap, byte, arrays

I have this hashmap:

```
HashMap <SocketAddress, Long> loadTable = new HashMap<SocketAddress, Long> ();
```

How can I get its byte number? I want to use it for TCP packet fragmentation purpose. 
also,
an object of class, How can I get its byte number?

Comment: What do you mean by 'byte number'?

Comment: number of byte, i.e long is 8 byte. I want to use it in a buffer

Comment: So do you want only the space you'd need for the longs, or the entire map including keys and such?

Comment: Yes, i need it for entier map. I put the long as an example.

Comment: You can't just get the amount of memory an Object takes up in Java. If you're going to transmit the map, you're probably going to serialize it into a byte array. Getting the length of that array would be trivial. If you won't be sending it, I don't see any reason why you would need this number. Perhaps if you give a more thorough illustration of what you are trying to accomplish.